# Eigenvalues of the Laplacian of a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I was reading in the internet that the eigenvalue $0$ of $L_G$, the Laplacian of a bipartite graph (with two or more edges) is at least $2$. Is this true? How can I see this?

Comment: No, it is not true. The bipartite graph with two vertices and one edge has eigenvalues $2$ and $0$.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that there are at least 2 edges.

Comment: Still false. Take the bipartite graph on four vertices that has the form of the letter "N". Its eigenvalues are $2$, $0$, and $\pm 0.5857...$.

Answer (score 2):

The number of times $0$ appears as an eigenvalue of $L_G$ is equal to the number of connected components in $G$.

Comment: And how you can proof this?

Comment: @Marc , As you know, any vector that is constant on the vertices of a connected component will be an eigenvector with eigenvalue 0. Consider the space of such eigenvectors with eigenvalue 0 -- what is its dimension? It's not too hard to show that you get a dimension for each connected component in your graph, and so this is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0. This was pretty terse, but I can elaborate more in a new answer if you'd like.

Comment: This answer is simply false. Maybe it is true for the geometric multiplicity, but this question is about algebraic multiplicity (or else it would be completely false).

Comment: @darijgrinberg;for a symmetric matrix algebraic multiplicity =geometric multiplicity

Comment: Oops! I was working under the assumption that the problem was true, whence your answer would contradict the problem. You are right, of course.